# Reactive Sankey Diagram in R Shiny with multiple dataframes as input

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

It's my first time creating a dashboard and I'm running into a problem I can't seem to solve. I have created a sankey diagram and I want to be able to interactively change its contents through different dataframes (in this example: level_1, level_2, level_3). I've only ever practiced this with a regular plot, where the input would come from a variable within one dataframe which is my starting point in this piece of code (e.g. I have a df$country, so I use input$country in my plot --> Then I could choose from different countries in the dashboard sidebar, in order to change the contents of the plot). I have no idea how to do this when the input has to come from seperate dataframes.

**My code: (in app.R)**

```
level_1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(seq(0,40), 15, replace=T ), 3, 5))
level_2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(seq(0,40), 20, replace=T ), 4, 5))
level_3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(seq(0,40), 25, replace=T ), 5, 5))

levels <- list(level_1, level_2, level_3)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "title"),
    
    dashboardSidebar(
        selectInput("in_levels", "Levels", choices = levels) 

        
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(sankeyNetworkOutput("widget1"))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
    
    links <- input$in_levels %>%
        rownames_to_column(var="source") %>% 
        gather(key="target", value="value", -1) %>%
        filter(value != 0)
    
    nodes <- data.frame(
        name=c(as.character(links$source), as.character(links$target)) %>% 
            unique()
    )
    
    links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name)-1 
    links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name)-1
    
    output$widget1 <- renderSankeyNetwork({
        sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
                      Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
                      Value = "value", NodeID = "name", fontSize = 14, nodeWidth = 60,
                      fontFamily = "Arial", iterations = 0, sinksRight=TRUE)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I thought maybe it would help to create a list(), levels, of all the dataframes, but that does not work. I get this error:

```
Error : Can't access reactive value 'in_levels' outside of reactive consumer.
i Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observer()?
```

I've googled reactive() and observer() to try to find out what my next step should be, but I haven't found the solution yet. It would be much appreciated if someone could give me advice on how to proceed, changes to make or something to read to increase my understanding.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot use a list of dataframes in the `choices` argument of `selectInput`. You can do `levels <- list(data1=level_1, data2=level_2, data3=level_3)` then `choices = c("data1", "data2", "data3")` then in `server` you get the selected dataframe with `levels[[input$in_levels]]`.

Comment: Thank you @StéphaneLaurent, this was incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access any `input` values in the server you need to use a reactive context. `shiny` won't allow you to do otherwise, but even if it did, if an `input` value is updated, the server-side code won't update to reflect the change. Since you want both `links` and `nodes` to be dynamic and both depend on each other, a neat solution might be to store both objects in a list as follows:

```
server <- function(input, output) { 
    
    plot_data <- reactive({

      # Perform all your computation inside this reactive!    

      links <- input$in_levels %>%
        rownames_to_column(var="source") %>% 
        gather(key="target", value="value", -1) %>%
        filter(value != 0)
    
      nodes <- data.frame(
        name = c(as.character(links$source), as.character(links$target)) %>% 
            unique()
      )
    
      links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name)-1 
      links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name)-1

      # Return the data in a list
      list(links = links, nodes = nodes)

    })
    
    # Access the datasets by calling the reactive and then treating as a normal list
    output$widget1 <- renderSankeyNetwork({
        sankeyNetwork(Links = plot_data()$links, Nodes = plot_data()$nodes,
                      Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
                      Value = "value", NodeID = "name", fontSize = 14, nodeWidth = 60,
                      fontFamily = "Arial", iterations = 0, sinksRight=TRUE)
    })
}
```

This is untested as my current version of R doesn't support the `network3d` package.

The concept of reactivity is tricky, but [chapter 3 of Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html) should be very illuminating if you're new to `shiny`.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand the workings of reactive() now. Applying your code does seem to work (no errors when running), but there's still a problem with the rest of my code (I'm getting an empty dashboard). 
I think the problem is with the structure of the *levels* list: I created the sankey diagram prior to the dashboard, with a df for each level. Therefore, my code for *links* is directed towards a dataframe (e.g. because of using rownames_to_column), but now I''m using a list() with dataframe inside. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: I don't think this is causing your issue since, e.g. `plot_data()$links` will return a data.frame and not a list. I think the issue is likely to be because you shouldn't use a list of data.frames as the `choices` argument to `selectInput()`. See [Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%c3%a9phane-laurent)'s comment above.